# Jest - Nesting Promises Assertion Never Returns

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm currently experimenting with the idea of using Jest for live API testing. Maybe there's a better tool, but I guess that's for another discussion. I'm facing an issue though where Jest returns the error: `Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.` when the assertion is inside of a second promise. I would think Jest would support promise nesting, but it doesn't seem to function as expected. It seems like the assertion isn't being returned. This syntax works fine with a single promise.

I'm using Jest V22.4.3 and Node V8.9.4.

new-ticket.test.js

```
const call = require('../resources/call');

test('Create a new, valid ticket.', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    return call.makePostRequest(~login-url~, {
        'username': 'xxxxx',
        'password': 'xxxxx',
        'version': 'xxxxx'
    }).then((response) => {
        call.makePostRequest(~ticket-url~, {
            'inInvType': 1,
            'inRetailOrClearance': 'R',
            'inAction': 'L',
            'inToken': response.token
        }).then((response) => {
            expect(response.retVal).toBe('0');
        });
    });
});
```

call.js

```
const https = require('https');

function makePostRequest(subURL, payload) {
    let options,
        request,
        body;

    // Convert our payload to JSON string.
    payload = JSON.stringify(payload);

    // Build our request options configuration.
    options = {
        hostname: ~base-url~,
        port: 8443,
        "rejectUnauthorized": false,
        path: subURL,
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': '*/*'
        },
        observe: 'body',
        responseType: 'json',
        reportProgress: true,
        withCredentials: false
    };

    body = '';

    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        request = https.request(options, (response) => {

            // Collect our response data as it streams in.
            response.on('data', (data) => {
                body += data;
            });

            // Once ended, resolve with data.
            response.on('end', () => {
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                resolve(body);
            });
        });

        request.on('error', (err) => {
            resolve(err)
        });

        request.write(payload);
        request.end();
    });
}

module.exports.makePostRequest = makePostRequest;
```

Answer (score 1):

How does test know when your test case is done?

Returning a Promise in your test case is the right idea, but your promise chaining breaks when you request the ticket URL. Try returning the Promise from that request.

```
const call = require('../resources/call');

test('Create a new, valid ticket.', () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

// => Returning the promise is the right idea but ...
    return call.makePostRequest(~login-url~, {
        'username': 'xxxxx',
        'password': 'xxxxx',
        'version': 'xxxxx'
    }).then((response) =>
// ... the inner block doesn't return anything.
// Without a Promise to signal there's async code running,
// Jest won't run this block. Try returning this call (delete the {})
        call.makePostRequest(~ticket-url~, {
            'inInvType': 1,
            'inRetailOrClearance': 'R',
            'inAction': 'L',
            'inToken': response.token
        }).then((response) => {
            expect(response.retVal).toBe('0');
        });
    );
});
```

If you're comfortable with async/await, you play with it as well:

```
const call = require('../resources/call');

test('Create a new, valid ticket.', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);

    let response = await call.makePostRequest(~login-url~, {
        'username': 'xxxxx',
        'password': 'xxxxx',
        'version': 'xxxxx',
    });

    response = await call.makePostRequest(~ticket-url~, {
        'inInvType': 1,
        'inRetailOrClearance': 'R',
        'inAction': 'L',
        'inToken': response.token,
    });

    expect(response.retVal).toBe('0');
});
```

Comment: Originally, I did try the async/await approach but it seemed that the second API call was being made before the first had returned a value. If I run your code as above, I receive a JSON error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
        at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)` but if I set `inToken` to a string and don't rely on the returned value from the first call, the test passes.

Comment: Oh! Yea, that makes more sense why your properties are quoted! Sorry Sean. I'll edit.

Comment: I think I might not have explained well what I meant. I'm saying that if I try to use the token returned in the promise from the first API call, I get an error. But, if I just hard code in a token in the second API call, everything proceeds without a problem. It looks like the second API call is being made before the first one has resolved.

Comment: Now I noticed an oddity when testing. Every other time I run the test, it breaks. No matter how long I wait between re-running the test, it always breaks every other time. I am experiencing this when using the token returned from the first API. It still works every time if the token is hard coded.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure as to why this would fail but I would suggest flattening your promise chain in order to test each of these separate.

Since you're using a pretty modern version of both Jest and Node you could use the `async`/`await` keywords since it'll make it clearer what's actually happening and relieve you of the callback mess you're bound to get yourself into.

Something like this should do the trick;

```
it('Create a new, valid ticket.', async () => {
    const res = await call.makePostRequest(~login-url~, {
        'username': 'xxxxx',
        'password': 'xxxxx',
        'version': 'xxxxx'
    });

    const response = await call.makePostRequest(~ticket-url~, {
        'inInvType': 1,
        'inRetailOrClearance': 'R',
        'inAction': 'L',
        'inToken': res.token
    });

    expect(response.retVal).toBe('0');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that my issue was completely unrelated to Jest, but I'll post it here just in case someone else ever has a similar issue. When making API calls, my Node scripts are pointed at a load balancer. In my code, I first make a call to request a new token. I then use that token in the second call to create a new transaction on the back end. The problem was that one of our servers had a clock set a few seconds different than the other. So, I would receive the token from the "faster" server and then sometimes the load balancer was directing me to the "slower" server. When I tried to use the token on the "slower" server, it was being considered invalid because it had been issued in the future.

To resolve this, I enabled NTP through this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-time-synchronization-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: Glad you figured it out. BTW, ever worked with Postman? You can also test and document your APIs with it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I use Postman every day but I didn't know it had the ability to handle automated testing. I'll take a look.